# Spring MVC (RESTful API): Validating payload dependent on a path variable

Tags: java, spring, rest, validation, bean-validation

#### Use Case:

- let's design a RESTful create operation using POST HTTP verb - creating tickets where creator (assigner) specifies a ticket assignee
- we're creating a new "ticket" on following location: `/companyId/userId/ticket`
- we're providing ticket body containing `assigneeId`:

  {
    "assigneeId": 10
  }
- we need to validate that `assigneeId` belongs to company in URL - `companyId` path variable

#### So far:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/{companyId}/{userId}/ticket", method=POST)
public void createTicket(@Valid @RequestBody Ticket newTicket, @PathVariable Long companyId, @PathVariable Long userId) {
  ...
}
```

- we can easily specify a custom Validator (`TicketValidator`) (even with dependencies) and validate `Ticket` instance
- we **can't** easily pass `companyId` to this validator though! We need to verify that `ticket.assigneeId` belongs to company with `companyId`.

#### Desired output:

- ability to access path variables in custom Validators

Any ideas how do I achieve the desired output here?

Comment: *"we need to validate that assigneeId belongs to company in URL - companyId path variable"* => so `Ticket` has `assigneeId` property and we need to ask database whether `assigneeId` belongs to a company with `companyId`. So we need both `Ticket` and `companyId`. Makes sense?

Comment: Sure. I missed that.

Comment: No worries, I updated the original Q (so hopefully it's clearer now).

Answer (score 2):

If we assume that our custom validator knows desired property name, then we can do something like this:

**Approach one:**

1) We can move this getting path variables logic to some kind of a base validator:

```
public abstract class BaseValidator implements Validator {

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz)
    {
        // supports logic
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors)
    {
        // some base validation logic or empty if there isn't any
    }

    protected String getPathVariable(String name) {
        // Getting current request (Can be autowired - depends on your implementation)
        HttpServletRequest req = HttpServletRequest((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()).getRequest();
        if (req != null) {
            // getting variables map from current request
            Map<String, String> variables = req.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.URI_TEMPLATE_VARIABLES_ATTRIBUTE);
            return variables.get(name);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

2) Extend it with your `TicketValidator` implementation:

```
public class TicketValidator extends BaseValidator {

    @Override
    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors)
    {
        // Getting our companyId var
        String companyId = getPathVariable("companyId");
        ...
        // proceed with your validation logic. Note, that all path variables
        // is `String`, so you're going to have to cast them (you can do 
        // this in `BaseValidator` though, by passing `Class` to which you 
        // want to cast it as a method param). You can also get `null` from 
        // `getPathVariable` method - you might want to handle it too somehow
    }
}
```

**Approach two:**

I think it worth to mention that you can use `@PreAuthorize` annotation with SpEL to do this kind of validation (You can pass path variables and request body to it). You'll be getting `HTTP 403` code though if validation woudnt pass, so I guess it's not exaclty what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You could always do this:

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

    @Autowired
    private TicketValidator ticketValidator;

    @RequestMapping(value="/{companyId}/{userId}/ticket", method=POST)
    public void createTicket(@RequestBody Ticket newTicket,
            @PathVariable Long companyId, @PathVariable Long userId) {

        ticketValidator.validate(newTicket, companyId, userId);
        // do whatever

    }

}
```

---

**Edit** in response to the comment:

It doesn't make sense to validate `Ticket` independently of `companyId` when the validity of `Ticket` depends on `companyId`.

If you cannot use the solution above, consider grouping `Ticket` with `companyId` in a DTO, and changing the mapping like this:

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/{userId}/ticket", method=POST)
    public void createTicket(@Valid @RequestBody TicketDTO ticketDto,
            @PathVariable Long userId) {

        // do whatever
    }

}

public class TicketDTO {

    private Ticket ticket;

    private Long companyId;

    // setters & getters

}
```

Comment: Absolutely, but I was trying to reduce the amount of controller's responsibilities and have these standalone validators invoked automatically by the framework.

Comment: @Xorty I have edited the answer with another option which reduces the controller's responsibilities.

Comment: thanks, I already though of that - but this would break my API clients which is off the table for now :/ (contract relies on using `Ticket`, not on `TicketDTO`)